# Python selenium open page in loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, webdriver

I want to do it in a loops in python:
for i in range (x)
1.open site
2. do my instructions
3.close page
my code:

```
 PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

   for i in range(1,100):

       driver.get("google.com")
       time.sleep(5)
       driver.quit()
       time.sleep(5)
```

and it works but only once, do all once and shows error. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that once you call `quit()` you terminated the session. Next call to the driver will fail as the session was destroyed. You need to create a new instance of the driver.

Using the context manager, use the `with` statement

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    with webdriver.Chrome(PATH) as driver:
        driver.get("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(5)
```

This will open and close the session without explicitly calling the methods.

Comment: This should nail the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `driver.quit()`. You don't need to close the driver window in every loop; you can just navigate to a new page using the same window. But if you do close one in every loop, then you also need to open one in every loop.

Comment: for i in range(1,100):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
       driver.get("google.com")
       time.sleep(5)
       driver.quit()
       time.sleep(5)

Comment: Perfect! Probably not necessary to sleep after window close.